# Configure dyango-pyodbc to use UnixODBC/FreeTDS instead of iODBC

Tags: python, macos, odbc

I have installed UnixODBC and FreeTDS via Homebrew using:

```
brew install unixodbc
brew install freetds --with-unixodbc
```

I've verified that I can connect via FreeTDS using `tsql` on the command line.

I get the following error however suggesting iODBC is still taking precedence:

```
Error: ('00000', '[00000] [iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen({FreeTDS}, 6): image not found (0)(SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Try as I might, I can't seem to find any explanation for how to tell the OS with ODBC driver to prefer.

EDIT: I found http://richbs.org/post/43142767072/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-from-unix-linux-mac and saw I was missing the environment variable `ODBCINI` however fixing this had no effect on the error about. It did however fix the `isql` which I had neglected up until this point.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so this what I did. Credit is owed to someone else, because I'm not that smart (at least that's my story - I made the change ages ago on a different machine and only rediscovered it today, and I assume something prompted it, but couldn't find it today).

I assume you are using a virtualenv (if not, then why not?).  You need to make the following change to `setup.py` in the pyodbc module (clone it first) (line 145 or thereabouts):

```
-        settings['libraries'].append('iodbc')
-
+        settings['libraries'].append('odbc')
+       #settings['libraries'].append('iodbc')
```

then run `python setup.py install`.  This (as I understand it) nixes the linking to iODBC, and will find the odbc libraries from unixODBC.

This may make it difficult to deploy, but I'm assuming when you deploy it will be to a Linux instance (which won't be as subject to the iODBC/unixODBC issue).  There is comment to the effect as to how to detect the different libraries in the posix-like else branch, so it's on someone's ticklist.

Comment: I noticed that this only works if you set: ``ODBCINI=/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini; export ODBCINI`` in your ``~/.profile`` or similar.